# If $p$ and $q$ are prime, and $p>q>3$, prove that $p^4 - q^4$ is divisible by $48$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, prime-numbers

Here is my proof:

$(p^4 - q^4) \implies (p^2 + q^2)(p-q)(p+q)$

All prime numbers greater than 3 can be expressed as $6x\pm1$, where $x$ is a positive integer.

let $p = 6n\pm1$ and $q = 6m\pm1$, we can show that:
$p^2 + q^2 = (6n\pm1)^2 + (6m\pm1)^2$.
$p^2 + q^2 = 36n^2 \pm 12n + 36m^2 \pm 12m + 2$, and such, implies $2(\mod6)$, and $2\mid p^2+q^2$.

With regards to (p-q)(p+q),$p$ and $q$ remainders can be $5(\mod6)$ or $1(\mod 6)$ respectively.

Case 1: $p = 5 (\mod 6)$, and $q = (1 \mod6)$

$p+q = 0(\mod6)$, and $p-q = (4 \mod 6)$, therefore:

$6\mid p+q$ and $2\mid p+q$

\

Case 2: $p = 1 (\mod 6)$, and $q = (1 \mod6)$

$p+q = 2(\mod6)$, and $p-q = (0 \mod 6)$, therefore:

$2\mid p+q$ and $6\mid p+q$

\

Case 3: $p = 5 (\mod 6)$, and $q = (5 \mod6)$

$p+q = 4(\mod6)$, and $p-q = (0 \mod 6)$, therefore:

$6\mid p+q$ and $2\mid p+q$.

In all cases, both expressions have a factor of 2, but only one has a factor of 6.
Therefore, $12\mid(p^2-q^2)$, and $24\mid(p^2-q^2)(p^2+q^2)$.

However, with my proof, I have only proved that p^4 - q^4, is a factor of 24. However, I don't know how to prove that the expression is also a factor of 48.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have $24\mid p^2-q^2$ and $2\mid p^2+q^2$, which is what you want.

Comment: I've been able to prove $2\mid p^2 + q^2$, but I don't know how to prove $24\mid p^2 - q^2$. How would I prove that?

Comment: you stated that's what you have already.  was that a typo?

Comment: Sorry, but I believe there is a bit of confusion. What I meant is that I have proved $2\mid p^2 + q^2$, but I have only proved $12\mid p^2 - q^2$, not $24 \mid p^2 - q^2$.

Comment: I guess there might be too many typos?

Comment: Oh, I see, give me a moment to edit the question statement..

Comment: Odd fourth powers mod $16$ are all $1$, and fourth powers not divisible by $3$ are all $1$ mod $3$, so ...

Comment: How do you prove that @RobertIsrael ?

Comment: Use @RobertIsrael 's suggestion, or else notice that $36k^2\pm12k$ is always a multiple of 8.

Comment: @Sam You could try $1^4$, $3^4$, $5^4$, $7^4$.

Comment: Alright, I see your point, but I'm not too sure how that brings me closer to the solution.
Now I know that $24\mid p^4 - q^4$ and $16\mid p^4 - q^4$, should I find the lowest common multiple of 24, and 16, (which would be 48), and that would be my solution?

Comment: You don't want to show that $p^4-q^4$ "is a factor of $48$". You want to show that $48$ is a factor of $p^4-q^4$.

Comment: `\pmod{16}` produces the correct parenthesis and space. E.g., `p^4\equiv 1\pmod{16}` gives $p^4\equiv 1\pmod{16}$.

Comment: I think you typed $p+q$ when you intended $p-q$ sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's obvious that $p$ and $q$ are both odd numbers as they are primes bigger than $2$. So we can actually deduce that
$$8|(p+q)(p-q)$$
This is because the sum and difference are both even and one of them must be a multiple of $4$. (This can be proven by mod $4$)

And, because $p^2$ and $q^2$ are both odd. We have
$$2|(p^2+q^2)$$
As we already have $16|(p^4+q^4)$, all we have to do is prove that one term from $(p+q)$, $(p-q)$ and $(p^2+q^2)$ is a multiple of $3$.

1. Case 1: $p\equiv\pm1\pmod3$ and $q\equiv\pm1\pmod3$, then $p-q$ is a multiple of $3$
2. Case 2: $p\equiv\pm1\pmod3$ and $q\equiv\mp1\pmod3$, then $p+q$ is a multiple of $3$

As both $p$ and $q$ are primes, they are not multiples of $3$.

Thus, we have proven it.

Comment: Don't type `(\mod 3)` which gives wrong spacing. Use `\pmod{3}` (the `pmod` stands for "parenthetical mod".

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: I didn’t see any other answer when I was typing this one. But anyway, I will strive to improve my speed of typing.

Answer (score 2):

The squares modulo $3$ are $0$ and $1$. In particular, the square of an integer not divisible by $3$ must be congruent to $1$ modulo $3$, and hence so is the 4th power. So $p^4\equiv q^4\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

If you square an odd number, the remainder modulo $8$ is $1$. This is easy to verify by simply looking at the squares of $1$, $3$, $5$, and $7$. That means that modulo $16$, the squares must be congruent to either $1$ or $9$ . Squaring again gives you $1$ or $81\equiv 1\pmod{16}$ (as $80=5\times 16$). Thus, $p^4\equiv q^4\equiv 1\pmod{16}$.

So we see that $p^4-q^4$ is divisible by $3$ and by $16$, hence by $48$ (their least common multiple) as desired.

Comment: Thanks, for the proof! Could you also provide resources for me to learn about modular arithmetic, what would be the rules of multiplying, dividing, exponentiating, etc.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).